# Usecase for write-only permission

Tags: linux, macos, sh, file-permissions

User can change the file permission to write only (010) in unix environment. But are there any usecase to keep the file permission to write only mode?.

Comment: A secure log file comes to mind, where `root` might have read permission, but a group ID under which a specific program runs would have write-only access...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be an instant where you want a set of users to write (append) into a file but not be able to read it; especially what other users may have written into it.

Comment: Is there any application with the above scenario?

Comment: As a professor, I may want to collect the response of all students to a question in a file but may not want them to see the response of others.  Also applicable any time you elicit ideas from a group where you may not want people to be able to see others' ideas.